# What's the better way to add multiple cookies - response.addCookie(cookie) or response.addHeader("Cookie", "value")

Tags: java, rest, servlets, cookies, http-headers

I want to add two cookies to the response, and would like to know what's the best practice to do that and why? This is a general question, but in my case i am sending the response to a non web browser REST client. Here are few options i could think of:

```
Option 1:

// create cookie and set maxage, domain etc. if applicable
Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie("cookie1", "value1");
response.addCookie(cookie1);


// create cookie and set maxage, domain etc. if applicable
Cookie cookie2 = new Cookie("cookie2", "value2");
response.addCookie(cookie2);

Option 2:

response.addHeader("Cookie", "cookie1=value1");
response.addHeader("Cookie", "cookie2=value2");


Option 3:

response.addHeader("Cookie", "cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2");

Can someone plz suggest/reason the best way from above options. 

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a server needs to set the `Set-Cookie` header not the `Cookie` header in the response. Second, the [`addCookie(Cookie)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29) method exist specifically to make your life easier, use it. A cookie can have much more than just a name and a value like in `cookie1=value1`. It can have an age, a path, a security level, etc. Writing these out in a String is a hassle.